# [MKAnnotationView setAnimatesDrop:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. But why?

Tags: iphone, mkannotationview, mkpinannotationview

```
(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView
             viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass: [MyLocation class] ])
    {
        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [theMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:placemarkIdentifier];
        if(annotationView == nil)
        {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:placemarkIdentifier];
        }
        else 
        {

            annotationView.annotation = annotation;         
        }

        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.animatesDrop = NO;
        annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.draggable = YES;


       return annotationView;
    }
}
```

`[MKAnnotationView setAnimatesDrop:]:` unrecognized selector sent to instance. 
I use a number of annotations classes (MKPinAnnotationView and MKAnnotationView).  May be this error occurred because I use the dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should assign different identifiers for both types of annotation views. Otherwise, you will end with `MKPinAnnotationView` where just an `MKAnnotationView` is expected and vice versa (which you've experienced here).